# Change to Mixed mode, Enable sa on SQL Server Express edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have installed SQL Server Express edition which comes along with MDT installation. From my Windows login, I'm able to access SQL Server, but it does not allow me to create login account. `Sa` is disabled.

In security login only two users are visible: `builtin\users` and `sa`. SQL Server is in Windows authentication mode.

How can I enable `Sa` and set password for it so that it helps to gain access to create account?

Comment: Follow this link.

https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/sql-server-authentication-mode.html

Comment: I have tried this method, did not work because windows account do have permission to modify.